# SQL Order by Results Count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

I have a table with data like the following:

```
Meal ID   |   Child    |  Fruit

1              Child A     Apple
2              Child B     Orange
3              Child A     Banana
4              Child A     Orange
5              Child C     Banana
6              Child A     Banana
7              Child C     Banana
8              Child A     Banana
```

and I need to order the results, highest to lowest, based on the fruit eaten, e.g. if the search query is Banana, the results will display as follows:

```
Banana Eaters (Highest to Lowest)

Child   |   Number of Bananas eaten

Child A     3
Child C     1
```

I'd start with:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM meals WHERE Fruit = 'Banana'";
```

But how do I sort the unique individual Banana-eaters as their own entry, then order the results by the ones who ate the most?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by child and use conditional aggregation:

```
select child, sum(fruit = 'Banana') `Number of Bananas eaten`
from meals
group by child
order by `Number of Bananas eaten` desc
```

If you want to exclude children who did not have any bananas:

```
select child, sum(fruit = 'Banana') `Number of Bananas eaten`
from meals
group by child
having `Number of Bananas eaten` > 0
order by `Number of Bananas eaten` desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e03b88d54a4cbd2463c6e47563a315be).

Answer (score 1):

use case when

```
select child,sum(case when Fruit='Banana' then 1 else 0 end) as bananaeaten
from meals
group by child
order by bananaeaten desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Child, count(*) as 'Number of bananas eaten' from meals
where Fruit = 'Banana'
group by Child
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: A from is missing in your statement and some words explaining

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see "Child B", then filter before aggregation:

```
select Child, count(*) as num_bananas
from meals
where Fruit = 'Banana'
group by Child
order by count(*) desc;
```